# How can you pass a string or list object to fabric as a parameter?

Tags: python, fabric

The problem I have is that my string is several words long, and actually contains the `'` character ... so I'm at a loss of how to pass the string I want.

I'm trying to do:

```
fab -H myhost.serv.com execute:"nc -zw1 159.1.1.1 9988 | gawk '{print $7}'","nc -zw1 159.1.1.2 9988 | gawk '{print $7}'"
```

However, this spits out:

```
Executing task 'execute'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 368, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 264, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 171, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/decorators.py", line 175, in real_decorator
    @wraps(func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

Is there any way around this? I'm calling it from a python script:

```
fabcmd = 'fab -H ' + ','.join(servlist) + ' execute:'
for cmd in commands:
    fabcmd += "\"{}\",".format(cmd)
print fabcmd
subprocess.call(fabcmd)
```

If there was a way to pass my command list object to fabric, that would actually be ideal.. so that I could just do something like...

```
fabcmd = 'fab -H ' + ','.join(servlist) + ' execute:' + commands`
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer here was unrelated to anything posted above -- I had the decorator ordering wrong in my `fabfile.py`:

**Original**

```
from fabric.api import parallel, task

@parallel
@task
def execute(*args):
    print args
```

**Modified**

```
from fabric.api import parallel, task

@task
@parallel
def execute(*args):
    print args
```

I don't know why this mattered... so if someone could explain, that'd be super.

Comment: probably because decorators are are executed from bottom up and the returned value is passed to the next decorator